# Does this code imply a class and method "relationship?"

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm working through exercises at exercism.io and I don't understand one of the exercises. My task is to write a small module that will be imported at runtime.

The code below is part of the exercise, and neither `Allergies` or `is_allergic_to` are defined in the test file. It is up to me to define them in my module.

```
def test_has_the_right_allergies(self):
    allergies = Allergies(5)
    self.assertTrue(allergies.is_allergic_to('eggs'))
```

1. I'm really not looking for a solution, as much as simple guidance on what a good programmer sees, and if it's true that I should approach the solution with a class and method, or just two functions with "method-capable" object (whatever THAT might be).
2. As a hobbyist programmer, I'm having trouble understanding the syntax. I read `is_allergic_to` as a method, but I don't know what type of object is being returned by the call to `Allergies()` Essentially, does the code imply that I create a Class `Allergies` that has a method `is_allergic_to`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, methods in classes are really no different than normal methods, except in the following two ways:

1. They are namespaced to the class. This means that you have to reference the class first before you can "see" or call the method.
2. They automatically get passed the instance (or the class) as the first argument. This first argument is normally referred to as *self*, but can be named anything else. You can also omit this if the method needs to work on the Class itself and not the instances.

So a "method capable object" is simply a method defined in a class, that takes the instance as the first argument:

```
class Foo(object):
   def some_method(self, a, b):
      self.foo = a
      self.bar = b
      return a+b

obj = Foo()
result = obj.some_method(1, 3) # `obj` is passed in as the instance (ie, self)
print(result) # This will print 4
print(obj.foo) # 1
print(obj.bar) # 3
```

You can also, explicitly call the method and pass in the reference of the instance, because its just a normal method:

```
result = Foo.some_method(obj, 1, 3)  # Not encouraged
```

In your example, the object return by `is_allergic_to` can should return a "true" or "falsey" expression (or value), that's what [`assertTrue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertTrue) expects:

```
assertTrue(expr, msg=None)
assertFalse(expr, msg=None)

Test that expr is true (or false).
```

One possible way to write the method would be:

```
class Allergies(object):
   # other methods here

   def __init__(self, name):
      self.allergies = []  # an empty list, to store allergies
      self.name = name

   def add_allergy(self, allergy):
      self.allergies.append(allergy)

   def is_allergic_to(self, allergy):
      return allergy in self.allergies
```

Comment: (1) Is it "necessarily" True in the original code that `is_allergic_to` is a method of class `Allergic()` ie "namespaced?"  (2) what is the `type` of object being returned by the call to `Allergic()`? It appears to be a list, but is it something else (more powerful/endowed)?

Comment: Yes, because in the original code - it is being called with the instance `allergies.is_allergic_to('eggs')`

Comment: The object return by `Allergic()` is an instance of the `Allergic` class.

Comment: Typo (by you & OP) in comments: The class you've defined is named `Allergies`.